# ReliableSqlConnection for .NetCore and .NetStandard

Tags: .net, sql-server, azure-sql-database, .net-core, .net-standard

I'm porting a class library from .NetFramework to either .NetCore or .NetStandard (still deciding which is the best fit).

My library handles a lot of SQL and uses the **EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling** and **EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Data** Nuget packages for transient error detection, retry strategies and reliable connections to SQL on Azure.

I am not able to use either library for both the **.NetCore** or the **.NetStandard** version - which I understand for **.NetCore** but I thought **.NetStandard** was backwards compatible with **.NetFramework**? In both cases I get an error from **Nuget** when I attempt to install:

> Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for '[ProjectName]'.

I am able to install **EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.Core** Which gives me the ability to handle my retry strategy but I still cannot use **ReliableSqlConnection** as it does not exist in this library nor in any others compatible with **.NetCore** or **.NetStandard**.

What is the difference then between **.NetCore** and **.NetStandard** in this regard? Why the same non descriptive error from **Nuget** on **.NetStandard**? Am I better off staying with **.NetFramework** for my needs?

Comment: This is a sideways approach and doesn't answer your questions so apologies in advance but have you considered a small rewrite? [Polly](http://www.thepollyproject.org/about/) works with .net-core and provides the functionality you require (and more).

Comment: I'll look into Polly - but I'm surprised that the Microsoft package for it is not available (yet?). Obviously I would prefer to not have to rewrite and retest...